# Get Element By Name - HTML DOM PHRASE

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm trying to phrase html source using HTML DOM phrase, I need to get a value inside a input tag, I tried this:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('input') as $link)
{
    $links[] = array(
        'value' => $link->getAttribute('value'), 
        'text'  => $link->nodeValue,
    );
}
```

This does work for me, but my web page has more that one input tag, but I want to get the value of specified input tag.

Let's say it's,

```
<input type="hidden" value="11111111" name="tele">
```

I tried to use `getElementsByTagName`, but it gives me an error.

Comment: Is this a PHP or a javascript question?

Comment: @Bergi : sorry its a PHP question, and I wanted a PHP answer but somebody has changed the tag PHP to Javascript..:)

Comment: I see. Shame on [@Schleis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/498699/schleis)! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the code you have now with a little modification

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('input') as $link) 
{
    if ($link->getAttribute('name') == 'tele') {
        $links[] = array(
            'value' => $link->getAttribute('value'), 
            'text'  => $link->nodeValue,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, after phrasing inputs tags I need to phrase again to find the tag with specified name.. thanks a lott.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `DomXpath`:

```
$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//input[@name="tele"]') as $link) {
    $links[] = array('value' => $link->getAttribute('value'), 'text' => $link->nodeValue);
}
```